# How to get number of objects in a pickle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Is there a short way to get number of objects in pickled file - shorter than writing a function that opens the file, keeps calling `pickle.load` method and updating `num_of_objs` by 1 until it catches `EOFError` and returns the value?

Comment: You can give [my `skip_pickle` function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8910284/222914) a try. You'll still have to loop over the entire file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't. The pickle format does not store that information.

If you need that type of metadata, you need to add it to the file yourself when writing:

```
pickle.dump(len(objects), fileobj)
for ob in objects:
    pickle.dump(ob, fileobj)
```

Now the first record tells you how many more are to follow.

Comment: If you know that in advance, why not just dump the entire list of objects in one go? Like `pickle.dump(objects, fileobj)`

Comment: @Matt: that would then require you to load that list in one step again too. What if you wanted to iterate over the objects one by one to save memory? If you pickle `objects`, then you can only load the whole list.

Comment: Hmyeah, seems to me if that'd be a concern (your list is so massive that it might cause memory issues), you wouldn't / shouldn't use pickle anyway. But fair enough

Comment: @Matt: why would you *not* use pickle? The [ZODB project](http://www.zodb.org/en/latest/) has built a transacional ACID compliant database around storing pickles, letting you store huge numbers of objects. And just because the writing side here had memory for the large list doesn't mean the reading side necessarily has.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of finding the length of a pickle, but if you are afraid of running an endless loop you could try the following,

```
company_id_processed=[]
with open("responses_pickle.pickle", "rb") as f:
while True:   
    try:
        current_id=pickle.load(f)['name']
        company_id_processed.append(current_id)
    except EOFError:
        print 'Pickle ends'
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to store and load data object with descriptive file name. For example, if you want to save two dataframes, you can name the pickle file as "datasets_name_2DFs.pickle". When you want to load them, you can simply get the number in the file name and use for loop equals to that number to get the pickle object. This is easier for me. For the code part, you can do what ever suits you. 
Or you can use other methods like this:

```
with open(path, "wb") as f:
     pickle.dump(len(data), f)
     for value in data:
           pickle.dump(value, f)
    
data_list = []
with open(path, "rb") as f:
     for _ in range(pickle.load(f)):
           data_list.append(pickle.load(f))
print data_list
```